# Where to find Hearty Bass?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I need some to upgrade my Zora Armour but can't for the life of me find any.

I know I found a pool somewhere where I caught five or six really easily (I have a feeling it was an unusual location, like the pool for one of the shrines but I checked those and they don't appear to have fish) but can't remember where now.

The Compendium's description hasn't helped much either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't forget you can use the Compendium entry with the Sheikah Sensor+ to help you find some more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few suggestions from [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75201400):

> I've been seeing tons of them in Faron's Lake Floria. Try there and its surrounding lakes/rivers.
>
> You can find them in Lake Akkala or whatever it was called.
>
> There is a pond in Mount Daphnes (think that was the one, on the west side)

[This thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75091934) also mentions Lake Floria, so that seems like a good place to try.

> I just found a bunch of them in the lake floria area in the very south of the map in faron
>
> caught the 15 i needed to upgrade my zora armor in about five minutes

Comment: Ah. Lake Floria, that seems about right. I probably caught them while trying to shoot Faroosh then and that's what I was thinking of. I'll try there next.

Comment: Also remember that for all ingredients, you can take a picture of them and the Sheikah Slate can track the nearest ones.

Comment: @MageXy Yeah, I just didn't want to have to run around every pond in the game waiting for it to beep...